# The Odin Project - Fundamentals 04 remove an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, rest-parameters

I have problems with exercise 04 at The Odin Project JS Fundamentals.
*Implement a function that takes an array and some other arguments then removes the other arguments from that array:*

```js
removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3); // should remove 3 and return [1,2,4]
```

I found a solution and tested it successful on my chrome-console, but it fails every test in the terminal (with npm test ...).
I don`t know whats wrong with the code.
My solution:

```
const removeFromArray = function(arr, ...args) {
  let a = arr;
  let b = args;
  let c = a.filter(d => !b.includes(d));
  console.log(c);
};
```

I used the variables a, b, c, d to make it more understandable for myself.
Could this be the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Your function should *return* the result, not *output* it. Do `return c;`

Comment: Hi trincot, thanks a lot, now it worked. I did not think that would be it. Thanks again!